# How to hide a segment of my website using PHP

Tags: php, css

So on my website we have a member database. All members have an access_level. What we want to do is make it to where `If (['access_level'] >= 10)` then a CSS class is visible. And if their access_level is below 10 then certain parts of the website are invisble.

Does anyone know how to make this PHP function?

Comment: 1. if you're talking about access levels, hiding something using CSS completely insecure.

Comment: 2. It sounds like you just want to conditionally echo a class: `<div class="<?php if ($can_access) { echo ' user-can-access-class'; } ?>`

Comment: There are a lot of ways to do that.
the simple and the insecure is to wrap your desired content with this condition and add its class if it's true.
If you were posted some code it could be easier to guide you.
What did you try anyway?

Comment: Please don't do this! In three clicks a savvy user can access any hidden content

Comment: Since you're testing their access level in php anyway, why not just.... **don't** render the content at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
<?php
$class = $array['access_level'] >= 10 ? ' class="visable"' : ' class="hidden"';
?>
<span<?php echo $class;?>>Test</span>
```

You really shouldn't output content that users shouldn't have access to to them though. I'd have a view for users that should have access and a view for no access.

This would output:

```
<span class="hidden">Test</span>
```

Note you will need to write the CSS rule. Probably

```
.hidden {
     display: none;
}
```